# Vue CLI install issues

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, command-line-interface

i'm learning Vue.JS and i need to install Vue CLI.

NodeJS : v13.8.0
Vue CLI : v4.2.2

I installed NodeJS without problems but when i go to my folder on terminal and install Vue CLI with (npm install -g @vue/cli) i got a lot of errors.

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Cedric:excli cedric$ npm install -g @vue/cli
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli'] {
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/cedric/.npm/_logs/2020-02-09T15_09_00_595Z-debug.log
```

I can create a project via terminal with: (vue create nameofproject) but it also contains error and i can't lauch npm run serve

```
gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/cedric/Documents/Projets Site Web : Apps/VueJs/excli/projet/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v13.8.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok 

Successfully created project projet.
Get started with the following commands:

 $ cd projet
 $ npm run serve

MacBook-Pro-de-Cedric:excli cedric$ npm run serve
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/cedric/Documents/Projets Site Web : Apps/VueJs/excli/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/cedric/Documents/Projets Site Web : Apps/VueJs/excli/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/cedric/.npm/_logs/2020-02-09T15_18_01_082Z-debug.log
```

If someone know how i can fix that it would be veryyy nice.
Thanks

Comment: The errors do not look related directly to Vue CLI. They look like issues with your npm setup. You may need to google for answers related to npm, macOS & <error message> like https://flaviocopes.com/npm-fix-missing-write-access-error/

Comment: To many error are included in the questino…

The EACCES means that you need to use sudo or install npm for user, for example google around `how to install nvm on MacOs`

The otheer part is gyp eror <= this one actually means that native buuild didn;t make it… Usually its "OK" and if you resolve the permission with advice above, this error will not hurt you at all. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks all for the answers, i find the problem. I was trying to create a project on a directory. when i create it on /user/myname it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you are on mac then try `sudo npm install -g @vue/cli` instead of `npm install -g @vue/cli` for the global installation.

Answer (score 0):

It's since the path of Node module has been missed, you can just type `sudo npm install -g @vue/cli` to install Vue, which means install vue under the global environment, either you can re-set your node module path.

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute `npm install -g` with superuser right (with `sudo` for exemple on linux) because it seems like your npm's directory is under superuser right.

You can also [change the npm's default directory](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally)